# PayPal IPN is not returning contact_phone

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am doing credit card payments with sandbox accounts in PayPal Pro.
The user MUST enter Firstname, Lastname, Email and Mobile phone, but when payment data is sent back to notify_url the "contact_phone" field is missing, and still does not appear when asking for transaction details.

Data sent back to notify_url:

```
(
    [mc_gross] => 35.00
    [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
    [payer_id] => XXXXXXXXXXXX
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payment_date] => 08:43:33 Apr 09, 2014 PDT
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [first_name] => XXXXXXXXXXXX
    [mc_fee] => 1.54
    [notify_version] => 3.7
    [custom] =>
    [payer_status] => unverified
    [business] => XXXXXXXXXXXX
    [quantity] => 1
    [verify_sign] => XXXXXXXXXXXX
    [payer_email] => XXXXXXXXXXXX
    [txn_id] => XXXXXXXXXXXX
    [payment_type] => instant
    [last_name] => XXXXXXXXXXXX
    [receiver_email] => XXXXXXXXXXXX
    [payment_fee] =>
    [receiver_id] => XXXXXXXXXXXX
    [txn_type] => web_accept
    [item_name] =>
    [mc_currency] => EUR
    [item_number] =>
    [residence_country] => GB
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [receipt_id] => XXXXXXXXXXXX
    [handling_amount] => 0.00
    [transaction_subject] =>
    [payment_gross] =>
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [ipn_track_id] => XXXXXXXXXXXX
    [format] => json
    [page] => 0
    [limit] => 10
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, there is a setting in your account that marks contact phone as a required field. (For Sandbox Business account - Profile - Website Payment Preferences - Contact Phone Number)

I just double tested it myself and it does send me contact_phone when using either guest checkout (credit or debit on PayPal site) or PayPal account with ExpressCheckout.

If you are trying to process payments using DoDirectPayment (direct creditcard) it will not pass this information back, the settings in your account only account for when they are directed to PayPal.

This information is not stored in the transaction, so you would want to store it before submitting the transaction to PayPal for processing.

Comment: The contact phone is sent me back when the user is paying with paypal, so no problem here. I set the mobile number as required for payments with credit card, so PayPal requires that the user enters firstname, lastname, email and mobile number. But no mobile number is sent back on credit card payments...

Comment: Are you talking about when you use DoDirectPayment API or if they are using guest checkout?

Comment: The user is paying as guest, so no paypal account is being use during the payment. And I set the guest checkout to be fulfilled with firstname, lastname, email and mobile number.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had it sent, either via sandbox or live either, for a wide variety of transaction types including all the subscription ones, 'cart', 'web_accept', 'send_money', 'invoice_payment', ... over a period going back to February 2013. Presumably they don't send it.

Comment: I am receiving "contact_phone" when paying with paypal, but not when paying with credit card. What's the meaning of asking mobile number to the user if it's not sent to me? :|

Comment: No, it's not PayPal, it's me. I am telling PayPal that user must enter his mobile phone... And PayPal does not send it back to me.